# Why is there 2 methods of calculating compound intrest?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a exercise in which I have to calculate compound interest when I searched how to do it I found 2 methods

1) $A=P(1+\frac rn)^{nt}$

2)$A_t=A_0e^{rt}$

I tried both got different results. What is the difference and why?

Comment: Drawing the wrath from everyone: in 2), you're using $n=\infty$ in 1).

Comment: The "$r$" in the two formulas are different. The answer depends on the exact wording of the question.

Comment: If your exercise says the interest is compounded a certain number of times, $n$, per year (assuming the units of $t$ are years), you use 1). If it says interest is compounded continuously, you use 2). When $n$ is big, the two are approximately the same. The difference between the two approaches $0$ as $n$ grows larger and larger.

Comment: @ Andre Nicolas the wording of the problem might be difficult as the question is not in English

Comment: It states a sum of $1250 is invested over 18 months at a yearly intrest rate of 7%

Comment: If the nominal rate is $7\%$ *compounded annually* then it would be $1250(1.07)^{1.5}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$A_n(t)=P(1+\frac{r}{n})^{nt} = P(1+\frac{r}{n})^{nt\cdot \frac{r}{r}} = P(1+\frac{r}{n})^{\frac{n}{r}\cdot rt} = P\bigg((1+\frac{r}{n})^{\frac{n}{r}}\bigg)^{rt}  $$

$$A(t) = \lim_{n\to\infty}P\bigg((1+\frac{r}{n})^{\frac{n}{r}}\bigg)^{rt} = P\bigg(\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{r}{n})^{\frac{n}{r}}\bigg)^{rt}$$

Let $h = r/n$ we have

$$A(t) = P\bigg(\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{r}{n})^{\frac{n}{r}}\bigg)^{rt} = P\bigg(\lim_{h\to 0}(1+h)^{1/h}\bigg)^{rt} = Pe^{rt}$$